# how to open another window form in backgroundworker in c#

Tags: c#, vsto

i need to run a time consuming process in backgroundworker and in that process i need to open a window too. All work good but when i call a UI in that process, it not allow me to work in that new window it just show waiting and when i cancel the backgroundworker process it not cancel either although i enable workersupportcancel. Here is my code

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        runCheck();    
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        }           
    }
    private void newBtncheck_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }       

 private void newBtncheck_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        this.backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111369/how-do-i-create-and-show-wpf-windows-on-separate-threads

Comment: @BillBerry i have seen that, but its not beneficial to me. I need to open another window in same thread. I use basic thread but it not working then i use backgroundworker and it also creating problems

Answer (score 6):

You need to wrap your code that opens new form in the `BeginInvoke()` of the calling form.

Put this in your `backgroundWorker1_DoWork()` method:

```
BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>{ 
  // place code to open new form here, for example new MyNewForm().Show()
}));
```

This is assuming your `backgroundWorker1_DoWork()` is a member of your main form class. If not, you will need to explicitly specify the instance of your main form:  `mainFormInstance.BeginInovoke(...)`

Comment: i have tried, h1 = new IDesignSpecWord2007.UI_Forms.HierarchyView(ref Globals.ThisAddIn.Application, ref docm); h1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {  h1.Show(); })); but its not working. window is not opening –

Comment: No, you have to call BeginInvoke from your main form, not from the new form you are creating. Kindly re-read my answer, it mentions this at the end: ... you will need to explicitly specify the instance of your main form: mainFormInstance.BeginInovoke(...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dispatcher` to ask UI thread to open dialog: (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8785492/1095390))

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ProgressDialog.ShowDialog()));
```